# Opening an application as an MDI form in WINFORMS app

Tags: c#, mdi

is it possible to take an application such as the mysql command line or notepad and display it in a windows forms application as an MDI form?

I have a relatively complex application that I would like to be able to access mysql directly through, for convenience. I would also like to be able to open notepad to allow simple text editing, but it seems foolish to reinvent the wheel and write my own text editor and incorporate it within the app just for convenience.

I just need a pointer as to where to go, as I currently have no clue, although I did consider using COM interop but I am not sure which of the native dlls to use.

I am using C# with Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

Comment: Embedding a window of another executable is rife with trouble.  The SetParent() winapi function has appcompat for Windows 3.x programs where this wasn't a problem.  The further you get away from 1992, the less likely that will work well.

Answer (score 0):

First I am not quite sure why you would want to do this however your best bet is going to be to find something on [codeplex.com](http://codeplex.com) and integrate it into your application.

An example would be 
http://dbexecutor.codeplex.com/

Then you can take the source and integrate it into your mdi application